# The "//" in "http://"

Tags: uri, protocols

I would like to know why designers of the URI standard chose to have `//` in the definition of URIs like `http://`.

Why make it so complex? Why not just use `http:`?

Comment: Well, Windows uses `\\ComputerName\Resource` to identify resources as well, so it's not a strange convention...

Comment: I don't mind the `//`. It lets us do things like `//example.com/image.png`.

Comment: if you let only the text http:  then the eye is confuze, where the url starts. Now is more clear.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's [the answer](http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2009/10/12/the-webs-inventor-regrets-one-small-thing/) (*The Web’s Inventor Regrets One Small Thing*).

In hindsight Tim Berners-Lee would remove it as well.

The reason it was included:

> The double slash, though a programming convention at the time, turned out to not be really necessary.

Comment: @Mehrdad - you'd have to know ahead of time that TBL was the primary on the syntax (although you could find that out via the RFC authorship listing) but FWIW there's lots of versions (of basically the same thing) by googling for "Tim Berners-Lee" "double slash", including some video in case you're more interested in seeing/hearing him say it. :)

Comment: Specifically, here's a more recent (AFAICT) video interview where he repeats that same comment about the double slash: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xh57ko_sir-tim-berners-lee-on-the-double-slash-in-the-web-address_tech

Answer (score 10):

RFC 2396 covers this, FWIW.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

The pseudocode in part 7 of section 5.2 in particular best answers your question, that the "//" is there to denote that what follows it is the authority part of the URI (since the pseudocode also makes it clear that it's not a required part of the URI).

```
if authority is defined then
         append "//" to result
         append authority to result
```

In addition, it's spelled out a bit more in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) section 3.

> When    authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two
> slash    characters ("//").  These restrictions result in five
> different ABNF    rules for a path (Section 3.3), only one of which
> will match any    given URI reference.

Comment: Thank you. However, it didn't explais the reason of this design choice, while `:` could have been sufficient. +1 for the search effort :)

Comment: @Vincent - added the 3986 reference that better explains it.  The URI syntax supports the authority part not being there at all (so, you could have a reference like http:foo/bar.html that would presumably have the same authority as the current context/page).  Now, since it's not a commonly used 'feature', as Simeon pointed out, TBL would have done well to optimize for the common case and drop those, but it's still a feature of the syntax, not a bug. :)

Comment: I chose your answer because it contains more details, but the answer of Simeon is as good.

Comment: @Vincent - IMHO, his is the better answer since it gives the more insightful response that TBL has of "whoops, my bad!" - mine has some technical info, but I'd much rather you mark his as the answer if you're willing to change it. :)